# convert from System.Type to the actual object

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

This is what I have:

```
<usercontrol>
    <usercontrol.resources>
            <Style x:Key="NorthStationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:XamComboEditor}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.StationListA}"/>
            </Style>
    </usercontrol.resources>

    <XamDataGrid CellChanged="NorthDataGrid_OnCellChanged" FieldLayoutInitialized="OnFieldLayoutInitialized" />
 </usercontrol>  

    Code control code behind:
    private void OnFieldLayoutInitialized(object sender, FieldLayoutInitializedEventArgs e)
            {
     e.FieldLayout.Fields["Equipment"].Settings.EditorStyle = Resources["NorthStationStyle"] as Style;
    }

    NorthDataGrid_OnCellChanged(object sender, CellChangedEventArgs e){

    if(e.Cell.Field.Name == "Station")
     //here I want to re-bind a different list to the ItemsSource property       

    }
```

In the cell changed if statement, if the cell that changed is "Station" I want to load a different equipment list into the for the Equipment column. Is this possible the way I have my code set up?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  A `Type` isn't a `XamComboEditor`.  Are you actually asking how to create an instance of the type?

Comment: You don't have a reference to an object. You have only a `Type`.

Comment: Ok I see. Can I somehow get the object that type is referring to?

Comment: What is *the* object?  You can probably use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a new instance, but you seem to be implying one already exists?

Comment: It doesn't refer to *an object*, it refers to a type, a *class of object*. Which object would 'comboType' refer to?

Comment: the object is a XamComboEditor that is set to a field in a XamDataGrid Fields["SomeField"].Settings.EditorStyle = Resources["MyStyle"]. "MyStyle" is of type XamComboEditor. What I'm trying to do is to change the item source of the XamComboEditor when something happens in the grid.

Comment: Too many questions.  Let's see where the source code for assigning/instantiating 'comboType' is.

Comment: I updated my initial question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

`XamComboEditor x = Activator.CreateInstance(comboType) as XamComboEditor` should work, assuming the class that the `System.Type` refers to (in this case, `XamComboEditor`) has a default constructor.